# Retrieve first & last name based on ID from other table

Tags: c#, sql

Currently I'm stuck with something that I think is easy to do but I'm going to ask it anyway.

I have a table called `zg_data` which looks like this:

```
+---------------------+------------------+
|       dataID        |      employee    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|         12          |        123       |
+---------------------+------------------+
```

And a table called `zg_employees` which looks like this:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      employeeID     |    Firstname     |     Lastname     |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|          123        |       Test       |       User       |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Now what I need to do is when selecting data from the `zg_data` table instead of it returning the `employeeID` I would like that it returns the `Firstname` & `Lastname` instead. I've been reading about joining tables but I haven't been able to figure it out just yet.

Comment: Yes, JOIN is the way to go. There are lot of tutorials on the net. You could try this one for example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm Then try to apply what you learn using the administrative tool of your database system (You haven't told us what database are you using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's basic `JOIN` operation, you should be able to figure it out on your own if you are familiar with it:

```
select d.dataID, e.Firstname, e.Lastname
from zg_data d join zg_employee e on d.employee = e.employeeID
```